# Kingdom Logistics for a 3.5 epic campaign

Tags: dnd-3.5e, game-recommendation, realm-management

I have been writing a campaign over the last month. We have six PC's and they each have partnered up with one other person to run a kingdom. There is the 3 PC kingdoms, as well as all a few other NPC kingdoms that I am running. I already have the base stuff each kingdom starts (depending upon location) but I need help with the basic things. How much income would a mine bring in or a farm or any type of resource that holds kingdoms together. What does it cost for upkeep on this. I am trying to keep the prices fair (based on location) and I am not quite sure where to start with this.

Are there any published rulesets adaptable to D&D 3.5 that support this style that I could use?

Comment: I urge you not to think about "prices" in a 3.5 sense. The 3.5 economy *isn't* and trying to use it to simulate logistics trains just leads to headaches. If you can articulate what level of abstraction you plan to use (and what you want the *outcomes* of the logistics successes and failures to be) we might be able to recommend a more accurate realm-model.

Answer (score 11):

See [Realm Management Rules That Work](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/realm-management-rules-that-work) and [What rpgs are focused on kingdom building and what sort of mechanics are used in each system?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1743/what-rpgs-are-focused-on-kingdom-building-and-what-sort-of-mechanics-are-used-in) for a variety of kingdom building rulesets you can crib for your game. Like, you could graft the REIGN kingdom system on top if you were willing to do some work. Some of those answers also mention 3.5e supplements and approaches.

If you're looking to do this very extensively, my favorite (I've not played REIGN or ACKS) is the original D&D 2e system [Birthright](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthright_%28campaign_setting%29).  Birthright was a complete boxed set/mini-setting all about epic realm management. Birthright has been adapted to 3/3.5e and 4e by the community and is available for free at [birthright.net](http://www.birthright.net/). It's probably the most "D&D'ey" answer.

Comment: +1 for the Birthright campaign setting. It's just great (from a lore perspective) and the mechanics are serviceable enough.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be very tempted to adapt the [Ultimate Campaign](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/) mechanics for Pathfinder to 3.5, the management aspects of that are nicely abstracted and 3.5 isn't a stones throw away from Pathfinder enough that it should fit.

Also this is all now online for free here: [Kingdom Building](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateCampaign/kingdomsAndWar/kingdomBuilding.html).

I've been in the Kingmaker campaign for PF for over a year now and the rules for developing cities and suchlike are easy to follow and good fun.

Answer (score 1):

[Fields of Blood](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/691/Fields-of-Blood-The-Book-of-War?it=1) was a rules system for domain management designed for the d20 system, it also includes war rules and the like. Very complete and easy to use.

[AEG Empire](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/3535/Empire?manufacturers_id=22&it=1&filters=0_0_1100_0_0) is another system released for d20. It's a little more abstract, more like Civilization inside DnD, but it has some good ideas.